# Traefik: Ajax call to https url resulting in Mixed Content, insecure XMLHttpRequest request error

Tags: javascript, ajax, xmlhttprequest, lets-encrypt, traefik

I am getting this error for all ajax call on my web application..

`Mixed Content: The page at 'https://one.mydomain.com' was loaded over HTTPS, but requested an insecure XMLHttpRequest endpoint 'http://one.mydomain.com/api/get-all-agents/'. This request has been blocked; the content must be served over HTTPS.`

The code also made the request as an absolute url on https.

All the applications are running on docker containers. Requests are proxied through Traefik.

I have tried adding adding backslash to the request to no avail.

The code making the call

```
var admin_base_url = "https://one.mydomain.com/

var url = admin_base_url + "api/get-all-agents/";

          $http.get(url).success(function(response){
              $scope.agents = response.agents;

          });
```

and

Here is my Traefik  toml configurations

```
debug = false

logLevel = "ERROR"
defaultEntryPoints = ["https","http"]

[entryPoints]
  [entryPoints.http]
  address = ":80"
    [entryPoints.http.redirect]
    entryPoint = "https"
  [entryPoints.https]
  address = ":443"
  [entryPoints.https.tls]

[retry]

[docker]
endpoint = "unix:///var/run/docker.sock"
domain = "mydomain.com"
watch = true
exposedByDefault = false

[acme]
email = "user@mydomain.com"
acmeLogging = false
storage = "acme.json"
entryPoint = "https"
onHostRule = true
[acme.httpChallenge]
entryPoint = "http"
```

and my Compose file

```
version: '3'

services:
  traefik:
    image: traefik:v1.7-alpine
    container_name: traefik
    restart: unless-stopped
    networks:
      - webgateway
    ports:
      - "80:80"
      - "443:443"
    volumes:
      - /var/run/docker.sock:/var/run/docker.sock
      - /home/ec2-user/traefik/traefik.toml:/traefik.toml
networks:
  webgateway:
    driver: bridge
```

and my application compose have this label

```
 labels:
      traefik.enable : "true"
      traefik.application.frontend.rule : "Host:one.mydomain.com"
      traefik.application-adminportal.port : "80"
    networks:
      - web
```

I have added `X-Forwarded-Proto = "https"` to the application labels and still having the same issue.

I viewed all the links suggested by the question model before asking here.

Please help.

**Update**

Browser redirecting to HTTP from HTTPS, then HTTP request resulted in the error
[image]

Comment: This issue has been resolved without making any change to Traefik settings. I used absolute url for ajax calls and globally allowed CORS.

Comment: It is better to post a real answer. [Self-answers are actually encouraged](https://meta.stackexchange.com/help/self-answer) (though some voters misunderstand them). It is a good idea to post a comment like mine here on the answer, ***immediately*** after posting the answer. ***Do not*** include such meta information in the answer itself.